# How can I pick 11 numbers in a string to an array?

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

I have a string like this:

```
MyString="5,9,12,15,16,22,23,28,33,45,65";
```

I should love to get it into an array like this:

```
Myarray[0]="5";

Myarray[1]="9";

Myarray[2]="12";

Myarray[3]="15";

Myarray[4]="16";

Myarray[5]="22";

Myarray[6]="23";

Myarray[7]="28";

Myarray[8]="33";

Myarray[9]="45";

Myarray[10]="65";
```

Is there someway to do this in `Java`?

Comment: String[] myArray= myString.split(",");

Comment: There isn't such thing as Android Java. Java is Java and it's the language that is used to develop Android applications.

Comment: Ah.Ok. Thanks expert developer.

Comment: Shall do this as a loop? for(int a=1;a<=11;a++){String[] MyArray = MyString.split(",");}

Comment: In Java, for variable names, the convention is to use camel-case i.e. instead of Myarray, you should be using myArray. It would look nice if you could follow that.

Answer (score 4):

```
String[] MyArray = MyString.split(",");
```

Comment: Shall do this as a loop? for(int a=1;a<=11;a++){String[] MyArray = MyString.split(",");}

Comment: There is no need for a loop. The `split()` method is used to split a string into an array of substrings, and returns the new array. The seperator "," in this case will be used for splitting the string. It doesn't change the original string.

Comment: I got it. I can say. I love You all.

Comment: @RobsonRobert Us too. `:)`

Answer (score 0):

From your comments, it seems you love loops (just like me!), if so, you can use Java `StringTokenizer`:

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(myString, ",");
String[] myArray = new String[st.countTokens()];    
int i = 0;

while (st.hasMoreElements()) {
    myArray[i++] = st.nextElement();
}
```